# VS Tools for Cordova overrides Android Icons

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

Every time I change a setting in the `config.xml` wizard, my Android Icons in the `config.xml` file get erased.

This is the entry in the config.xml file that sets the icons for android:

```
  <platform name="android">
    <splash density="land-hdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png" />
    <splash density="land-ldpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png" />
    <splash density="land-mdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png" />
    <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png" />
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="android">
    <icon density="ldpi" src="res/icons/android/mipmap-ldpi/ic_launcher.png" />
    <icon density="mdpi" src="res/icons/android/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
    <icon density="hdpi" src="res/icons/android/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="res/icons/android/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="res/icons/android/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
    <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="res/icons/android/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
  </platform>
```

After I change something in the wizard (like the version code), the icons are gone. My iOS Icons are still there, though.

Comment: What wizard do you mean? Surely the wizard is just creating a new config.xml and of course it will overwrite existing one, you should manually edit the config.xml after your initial app has been created.